# Error in Planning group with MoveIt! Setup Assistant

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, ros-kinetic, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I had successfully created a working URDF file for the UR5 robot with a Kinect sensor attached to the end-effector. I have verified the URDF file using check_urdf. I wished to use the URDF file with Gazebo as well as RViz, for which I was following [this link](https://github.com/AS4SR/general_info/wiki/ROS-MoveIt!-and-Gazebo-Integration-(WIP)). I am using ROS Kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04.

For creation of the MoveIt! configuration package, I was referring to [MoveIt setup assistant tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html), [this tutorial](http://www.theconstructsim.com/ros-moveit/) and [the ROS Industial tutorial](http://ros-industrial.github.io/industrial_training/_source/session3/Build-a-Moveit!-Package.html).

I have created the self-collision matrix and the virtual joints as per the ROS-I tutorial. The ROS-I suggested that I add the planning group with the name 'manipulator' and by adding a Kinematic chain from the base_link to the tool0 (end-effector) link. However when I try to add robot poses with this planning group, I get this following error message.

> Unable to find joint model group for group: manipulator  Are you sure this group has associated joints/links?

Because of this, I was not able to visualise the joint motions as well as set a pose. Any particular reason for this error? I have attached the related pictures for reference. Thanks in advance.

[image: Self Collision checking]

[image: Virtual Joints]

[image: Planning Groups_General]

[image: Planning_Groups_2]

Edit: I have checked the same procedure with standard URDF files from the UR5 and UR10 robot. I am still getting the same error.

Update: Added the link to the URDF file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_6DP_EUM1Y2F6r3TWuw4ewi-PQp1AUAe/view

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290983/error-in-planning-group-with-moveit!-setup-assistant/) by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2018-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it. Turns out it was a stupid mistake. While making the new planning group, I was adding an extra space at the end of the planning group name 'manipulator' which was causing an error and showing that this particular planning group doesn't exist.

---

Originally posted by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) with karma: 105 on 2018-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0